# How to align text to the left side when div is rotated?

Tags: html, css, rotation, alignment

I'm currently struggling with a layout problem. I'd like to create a rotated div with a text inside it, but the text should not be rotated; I'd like the text to be aligned to the left side but keep the edge of the rotated div.

Here's the simplified version of what I've tried so far:

```css
.container {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  position: relative;
 }

.text {
 background-color: red;
 color: white;
 transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="text">
  <p>
   This is some text.
  </p>
  <p>
   And here's the second paragraph.
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

What I'd like to have is the second paragraph to be aligned to the left side of the rotated div.

The desired effect:

[image: rotated div with text aligned left]

Is it possible with CSS or should I somehow try with JS?

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for editing and help, I've added the image.

Answer (score 2):

Removed the div, and achieve the result you want.

```css
.container {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  position: relative;
 }

p {
/* background-color: red;*/
 color: white;
 transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <p>
   first paragraph
  </p>
  <p>
   second paragraph.
  </p>
  <p>
  third paragraph
  </p>
  <p>
  fourth paragraph
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really, I've added an image with the desired effect.

Comment: see if the answer fits your questin now

Comment: Yes, but what if the text breaks the line and the next line starts from the same line as the previous (in one element)? I'd like it to have an indent, just like the <p> element. Is it possible?

Comment: can you make an example? The <pre> might answer your question, if I understood correctly. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp